# Passe $model data with renderPartial in Yii

Tags: yii

I've been trying this for about 2 hours and nothing was changed.

I have a model `Users`, I wanted to pass its `_form.php` view to `views/site/index.php` like that :

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('/users/_form', array('model'=>Users::$model)); ?>
```

the result: the layout has gone, and the form doesn't displayed.

Any help guys ? and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <?php echo $this->renderPartial('/users/_form', array('model'=>Users::$model)); ?>
```

should read

```
 <?php $this->renderPartial('/users/_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

assuming you have instantiated `$model` already. If not

```
 <?php $this->renderPartial('/users/_form', array('model'=>new User)); ?>
```

should work.

Comment: `Users::$model` searches for a static variable `$model` (that doesn't exist?) inside the `Users` class instead of instantiating it.
Also the rendering methods echo views/text etc by default so the `echo` at the beginning is not required.
For more information on `renderPartial()` go to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail

Comment: Another issue, the form doesn't validate my data entered ?!!